# How can we use store in Ember 2.x

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am upgrading my app from Ember 1.10 to 2.2. I have used store in 1.10 and is working fine there, but when I try to copy that in 2.2, it gives me error because of store. Is there a specific way to initialize the store as I am not able to get the store all the time. In some controllers, not all the data of the store is available. Please help

Comment: no, there's no specific way to initialize it. Do you use ember-cli? What errors do you get?

Comment: Like @Jeff commented, we need more information to help you debug the problem. Can you post the versions of the libraries you are using, and what the error is?

Comment: Ember: 2.2.0, ember-data: 2.2.1. Sometimes I get "store" undefined (usually when I hit refresh) and I never get the data in controllers other than application. I am not using ember-cli. Earlier I was using Ember: 1.8.1 and ember-data: 1.0.0-beta.11